# How do I Interactively Retrieve Child Subprocess Output and Send Input using Popen?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Sorry in advance, I've tried searching through similar questions, but I've come to a dead-end.  I've figured out a way around this issue, but I still want to figure out how to use the subprocess module effectively.

I'm writing a Python function that interacts with VMWare's OVFtool.exe (Windows environment) via the subprocess module using Popen to export an OVA file from VSphere.  I've made it to the point where I can see and interact with the username and password prompts from the OVFTool.

When I run the below code, it shows me the prompt from the ovftool.exe for the username, and I write the username to stdint and flush, and then I see the prompt for the password.  I input the password write it to stdin and it then flushes stdin but then it just stalls on the last **proc.stdout.readline(4)** with no errors or output.  I'm just using a test username/password for now, and it should give me the username and password prompts again, but it seems to just hang on that readline function.  My thought is maybe the ovftool process is spawning another process or maybe I'm misunderstanding how to buffer and submit input via stdin (likely)?

I've changed around the buffer amount, I've tried subprocess with and without the universal_new_lines, bufsize=1, and shell=True arguments.  What I ended up doing as a workaround is I pass the username and password via the command-line argument for ovftool.exe.  Still, I'd like to know what I am doing wrong because I'd like to be able to capture the output in real-time using Popen and interact with it as needed.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
def export_extract_ova_file():
    vm_name = input("What is the name of the vm you are exporting?")
    print(f"Exporting {vm_name} from VSphere.")
    with subprocess.Popen(f"\"{ovf_tool_path}\" vi://example_ip/{vm_name}"
                            f"./{vm_name}.ova", text=True,
                            stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True) as proc:
        proc_read = proc.stdout.readline()
        print(proc_read)
        proc_read = proc.stdout.readline(10)
        print(proc_read)
        input("Please enter your username")
        proc.stdin.write(username + "\n")
        proc.stdin.flush()

        proc_read = proc.stdout.readline(10)
        print(proc_read)
        password = input("Please enter your password")
        proc.stdin.write(password + "\n")
        proc.stdin.flush()
        proc.stdout.flush()
        sleep(1.0)
        proc_read = proc.stdout.readline(4)
        print(proc_read)
```

Comment: This (monitoring an interactive process's output and triggering input when prompted for) is a job for `pexpect`. Much easier to use a tool built for the job than to invent the necessary parts yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.  I really wasn't sure how complex my question was, so I'll explore `pexpect`.